# Implementing SLAM on a car-like robot using the navigation stack in ROS

Tags: navigation, base-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,
I have been assigned to work on Ackermann type robot and my task is to make it autonomous and implement SLAM on it. I did consider ros-navigation stack and I came across this post http://answers.ros.org/question/9059/how-can-i-use-the-navigation-stack-on-a-carlike/.

Before I shoot out my questions,I would like to give a picture of whats going on.
here is video for my robot:http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8fZYF8Zn3zA

**Components of the robot:**
1.sdc2130 motor driver
2.encoders from US digital
3.SICK LIDAR(LMS-200)
4.2 lead acid(12 V ) batteries.
5.2 DC motors

**Goals:**
1.To achieve SLAM in unkown environment and also to achieve autonomous navigation and obstacle avoidance.

**Tasks accomplished:**
1.Developed a ros node for the motor control as shown in the video.
2.Developed a ros node for reading the encoder values and pumping out the data to the odometry node.

**Things yet to be done:**
1.identifying the ideal motion primitive and implementing it in the ros-navigation(which I have no clue how to start).
2. Rewriting the local planner.

**Questions**:

1. I would like to know whether the navigation stack could be implemented successfully in this type of robot.
   2.Is there any other approach in ROS to achieve SLAM in this type of robot?.

I am aware that the files trajectory_planner.cpp ,trajectory_planner.h(Local planner) in navigation/base_local_planner are the ones which need editing. I also need to know how to choose the right motion primitives in SBPL and how to implement it in ros navigation stack.

Please share your views on this. Thanks for your time.

regards,
Karthikeyan Yuvaraj

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40447/implementing-slam-on-a-car-like-robot-using-the-navigation-stack-in-ros./) by [metal](https://answers.ros.org/users/1575/metal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 174 on 2012-08-02

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I am trying to implement navigation stack for robots with steering control.
You can see current version on http://code.google.com/p/lego-nxt-car-like/, but there are many errors.
You need "ackermann_plugin_gazebo", "car_like_simulation", "carlike_local_planner" folders.

I have implemented navigation stack only gazebo robot model. You can try run simulation by command

```
roslaunch car_like_simulation car_like_simulation.launch
```

Example of simulation http://youtu.be/sJykUs0xleE

Regards, Alex

---

Originally posted by [Alexandr Buyval](https://answers.ros.org/users/691/alexandr-buyval/) with karma: 641 on 2012-08-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-08-07**:
Thanks for the link, your work looks interesting. If you like, we should link it to the Ackermann steering wiki page.

**Comment by [Alexandr Buyval](https://answers.ros.org/users/691/alexandr-buyval/) on 2012-08-07**:
Thank you. I do not mind.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a ROS [Ackermann steering interest group](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Ackermann%20Group), which held some discussions and a review on the subject. That work is still quite preliminary. There is no general navigation solution that I know about.

For motion primitives, we recommend using the messages in the [ackermann_msgs](http://ros.org/wiki/ackermann_msgs) package.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-08-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3